# React Native App Debug mode works fine, Release mode crashes (App Registry and evaluating 'a.View.propTypes.style')

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, react-native

I've been implementing map box recently, and I've updated to the latest version of react-native, gradle, and what not. The app runs absolutely fine in debug mode, but as soon as I run it in release mode it crashes immeidately with no warning screen at all. I'm using the new propTypes, and so on.

Please see the output log

Okay I apologise, whilst the above works in debug mode, the app is now crashing when building a release and I'm confused.

I'm attempting to build a release, and the crashes immediately although works fine in debug mode:

```
11-23 00:48:14.499: E/SDAgentPackageStateReceiver(6040): Not going to handle 'com.goclustr.clustr'!
11-23 00:48:14.704: E/CS/CscParser(20341): mps_code.dat does not exist
11-23 00:48:14.720: E/CS/CscParser(20341): mps_code.dat does not exist
11-23 00:48:14.735: E/CS/CscParser(20341): mps_code.dat does not exist
11-23 00:48:14.884: E/Launcher.Model(1564): onPackageAdded :com.goclustr.clustr
11-23 00:48:14.906: E/ApplicationPackageManager(1564): checkSettingsForIconTray value : 0
11-23 00:48:14.907: E/ApplicationPackageManager(1564): checkSettingsForIconTray value : 0
11-23 00:48:15.589: E/ReflectField(20468): Incorrect type : Fallback exception
11-23 00:48:15.589: E/ReflectField(20468): Incorrect type : Fallback exception
11-23 00:48:15.778: E/SemAffinityControl(20435): SemAffinityControl: registerfunction enter
11-23 00:48:16.281: E/SensorService(6040): getSensorList a sensor (MAX86902) without holding its required permission: com.samsung.permission.SSENSOR
11-23 00:48:16.281: E/SensorService(6040): getSensorList a sensor (HRM Ambient Light Canceling) without holding its required permission: com.samsung.permission.HRM_EXT
11-23 00:48:16.281: E/SensorService(6040): getSensorList a sensor (HRM Proximity detecting) without holding its required permission: com.samsung.permission.HRM_EXT
11-23 00:48:16.281: E/SensorService(6040): getSensorList a sensor (HRM Sensor) without holding its required permission: com.samsung.permission.SSENSOR
11-23 00:48:16.281: E/SensorService(6040): getSensorList a sensor (Sensor Diagnostic Monitor) without holding its required permission: com.samsung.permission.SSENSOR
11-23 00:48:16.297: E/Finsky(311): [1] com.google.android.finsky.wear.bk.a(3): onConnectionFailed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null, message=null}
11-23 00:48:16.633: E/AndroidRuntime(20526): Process: com.goclustr.clustr, PID: 20526
11-23 00:48:16.633: E/AndroidRuntime(20526): com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'a.View.propTypes.style'), stack:
11-23 00:48:16.633: E/AndroidRuntime(20526): global code@841:9
11-23 00:48:16.633: E/AndroidRuntime(20526):    at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.showOrThrowError(ExceptionsManagerModule.java:56)
11-23 00:48:16.633: E/AndroidRuntime(20526):    at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportFatalException(ExceptionsManagerModule.java:40)
11-23 00:48:16.633: E/AndroidRuntime(20526):    at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:374)
11-23 00:48:16.633: E/AndroidRuntime(20526):    at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:162)
11-23 00:48:16.633: E/AndroidRuntime(20526):    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
11-23 00:48:16.633: E/AndroidRuntime(20526):    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31)
11-23 00:48:16.633: E/AndroidRuntime(20526):    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:194)
11-23 00:48:16.850: E/ApplicationPackageManager(6833): checkSettingsForIconTray value : 0
11-23 00:48:16.850: E/ApplicationPackageManager(6833): checkSettingsForIconTray value : 0
11-23 00:48:16.865: E/ApplicationPackageManager(6833): checkSettingsForIconTray value : 0
11-23 00:48:17.259: E/ReactNativeJS(20526): Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling unmountApplicationComponentAtRootTag)
11-23 00:48:18.615: E/SMTCodec(20807): Fail to load libsmtcodec.so
11-23 00:48:18.616: E/SMTCodec(20807): [VoiceCodec] Can use only PCM mode. 
11-23 00:48:19.302: E/HealthDataStore(20878): disconnectService: Context instance is invalid
11-23 00:48:20.297: E/HealthDataStore(20903): disconnectService: Context instance is invalid
11-23 00:48:20.588: E/com.strava.util.Benchmark(20998): "com.strava.StravaApplication.total" took 285 ms, but expected 60-175 ms
11-23 00:48:21.328: E/ActivityThread(20789): Failed to find provider info for com.samsung.accessory.saproviders.sasvoice.util.SASVoiceNativeAppProvider
11-23 00:48:21.486: E/HealthDataStore(20878): disconnectService: Context instance is invalid
11-23 00:48:27.157: E/svoiceapi(20789): in pds_open function, Caught RCF::Exception: Unable to establish network connection.
11-23 00:48:27.158: E/svoiceapi(20789): KEY : rampcode, VALUE : dash
11-23 00:48:27.158: E/svoiceapi(20789): KEY : reason, VALUE : Unable to establish network connection
11-23 00:48:45.574: E/CS/CscParser(21190): mps_code.dat does not exist
11-23 00:48:45.588: E/CS/CscParser(21190): mps_code.dat does not exist
11-23 00:48:45.602: E/CS/CscParser(21190): mps_code.dat does not exist
11-23 00:48:46.291: E/SensorService(6040): getSensorList a sensor (MAX86902) without holding its required permission: com.samsung.permission.SSENSOR
11-23 00:48:46.291: E/SensorService(6040): getSensorList a sensor (HRM Ambient Light Canceling) without holding its required permission: com.samsung.permission.HRM_EXT
```

As you can see there is an error for

```
11-23 00:48:17.259: E/ReactNativeJS(20526): Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling unmountApplicationComponentAtRootTag)
```

and

```
com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'a.View.propTypes.style'), stack:
```

None of which are a problem in debug mode

Thanks very much!

Comment: I think you must change the View.propTypes.style in your code since it's already deprecated, change it to ViewPropTypes.style. Also import { ViewPropTypes } from 'react-native'; Docs was here https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/viewproptypes.html but it's now not found, I think they will make some changes to it.

Comment: Some of your node-modules use View.propTypes.style use instead ViewPropTypes.style. From log you posted can't tell which one. Try updating your modules to the newest version. Sometimes even updating node-modules doesn't help because many of npm libs still didn't update their code, but most of "popular" ones did.

Comment: Thanks @zarcode I've added an answer, but for me it appears to have been `react-native-router-flux` on version `0.38.0` but when upgraded to `4.0.0-beta.24` the problem was resolved. Running `jscodeshift -t react-codemod/transforms/React-PropTypes-to-prop-types.js myapp/` helped additionally.

Comment: Nice, I like your solution. I have forked library that has old code until they update it.

Comment: Thanks @zarcode Pleased I could help, it was frustraing at first, but Android device monitor when running the release build seemed to provide some useful hints along with everything else

Answer (score 3):

Using [react-codemon](https://github.com/reactjs/react-codemod), run on your projects directory

jscodeshift -t react-codemod/transforms/React-PropTypes-to-prop-types.js myapp/

This will resolve updating proptypes for your source code and any node modules.

Re-installing node modules will require running the command again it seems.

Please follow instructions over at https://github.com/reactjs/react-codemod but essentially once you've installed `jscodeshift`, and you've downloaded the `react-codemod` files as above for the various commands such as transforming React.propTypes to PropTypes and so on.

`myapp/` here corresponds to my entire application project directory so the entire react-native project.

Secondly, consider the project dependencies you're using. For example in my case I was using `react-native-router-flux` at version `0.38.0`, the app would work in debug mode, but crash in release. I attempted to upgrade to the latest beta version of `4.0.0-beta.24` and the problem was resolved.